# How to create one model class to use with multiple API methods that require different JSON payloads?

Tags: c#, api, testing, json.net, nunit

I have a several APIs under one service. The APIs take different JSON payloads. I want to create one model class with attributes and values and set them. Can this be achieved with one model class to use for the several APIs? For example, I have one API method which takes a JSON id and name and another API that takes userID and color. How can I indicate which specific attritubes and values to apply when sending the request to the specific API that requires those data? I am using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)` in my Send request.

Currently I have the following in my model. I am using the instance of the TagModel class the assign the values but when using the SerializeForApiMethod and stating which method I need the specific values it takes entire model values assigned. I am trying to just extract the ones I need with the specific method name.

````
 public class TagModel
    {

        public static TagModel model = new TagModel
        {
            endpointIds = new List<int> { -2147483612, -2147483611 },
            tagIds = new List<int> { 35, 37 },
            id = -2147483639,
            parentId = 37
        };

        [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateEndpointsToTags")]
        public List<int> endpointIds { get; set; }
        public List<int> tagIds { get; set; }

        [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateEndpointsFromTags")]
         public int id { get; set; }
         public int parentId { get; set; }
    } 


This is m helper class:
```public class Helper
    {

        [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
        public class UseWithApiMethodsAttribute : Attribute
        {
            public UseWithApiMethodsAttribute(params string[] methodNames)
            {
                MethodNames = methodNames;
            }

            public string[] MethodNames { get; private set; }
        }

        public class SelectivePropertyResolver : DefaultContractResolver
        {
            public string ApiMethodName { get; private set; }

            public SelectivePropertyResolver(string apiMethodName)
            {
                ApiMethodName = apiMethodName;
            }

            protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
            {
                JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
                if (member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
                {
                    var att = ((PropertyInfo)member).GetCustomAttribute<UseWithApiMethodsAttribute>(true);
                    if (att != null && !att.MethodNames.Contains(ApiMethodName))
                    {
                        prop.Ignored = true;
                    }
                }
                return prop;
            }
        }

        public  string SerializeForApiMethod(Object model, string methodName)
        {
            var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
            {
                ContractResolver = new SelectivePropertyResolver(methodName),
                Formatting = Formatting.Indented
            };
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, settings);
        }
    }

This is my Method class using the SerializeForApiMethod method
```public HttpWebResponse UpdateEndpointsFromTags()
        {
            RequestHandler requestor = new RequestHandler(BaseUrl + "UpdateEndpointsFromTags", HttpVerb.POST, AuthenticationType.Bearer);
            return requestor.SendRequest(helper.SerializeForApiMethod(model , "UpdateEndpointsFromTags"));            
        }

        public HttpWebResponse UpdateEndpointsToTags()
        {
            RequestHandler requestor = new RequestHandler(BaseUrl + "UpdateEndpointsToTags", HttpVerb.POST, AuthenticationType.Bearer);
              return requestor.SendRequest(helper.SerializeForApiMethod(model, "UpdateEndpointsToTags"));      
        }
````

Complex Payload

[image]

Comment: From your example it sounds like the APIs are completely different from each other.  If that is the case, I'm not sure I understand what you gain by using the same model for them.  Can you explain more about why you want to do this?

Comment: In the framework we have a Model folder which holds all the models for each service. For example we have a service called User. In the User service i have one API that created a  user and another one updates a user. Both takes different Json payload. Can I create different model class under one parent model class? I am trying to avoid creating so many models

Answer (score 0):

You can selectively include or exclude properties during serialization using a custom [`ContractResolver`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm).  You could introduce a custom attribute to indicate which properties in your model should be included with which API method(s).  Then have the resolver look for those attributes and ignore the model properties that don't match the API method for which you are serializing.

Attribute code:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Property)]
public class UseWithApiMethodsAttribute : Attribute
{
    public UseWithApiMethodsAttribute(params string[] methodNames)
    {
        MethodNames = methodNames;
    }

    public string[] MethodNames { get; private set; }
}
```

Resolver code:

```
public class SelectivePropertyResolver : DefaultContractResolver
{
    public string ApiMethodName { get; private set; }

    public SelectivePropertyResolver(string apiMethodName)
    {
        ApiMethodName = apiMethodName;
    }

    protected override JsonProperty CreateProperty(MemberInfo member, MemberSerialization memberSerialization)
    {
        JsonProperty prop = base.CreateProperty(member, memberSerialization);
        if (member.MemberType == MemberTypes.Property)
        {
            var att = ((PropertyInfo)member).GetCustomAttribute<UseWithApiMethodsAttribute>(true);
            if (att == null || !att.MethodNames.Contains(ApiMethodName))
            {
                prop.Ignored = true;
            }
        }
        return prop;
    }
}
```

Then, mark up your model with the new attribute like this, for example:

```
public class Model
{
    [UseWithApiMethods("method1", "method3")]
    public int id { get; set; }

    [UseWithApiMethods("method1")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [UseWithApiMethods("method2")]
    public int userId { get; set; }

    [UseWithApiMethods("method2")]
    public string color { get; set; }
}
```

Finally, create a helper method which uses the resolver to serialize the model:

```
public static string SerializeForApiMethod(object model, string methodName)
{
    var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new SelectivePropertyResolver(methodName),
        Formatting = Formatting.Indented
    };
    return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, settings);
}
```

Call it like this, for example:

```
string json = SerializeForApiMethod(model, "method1");
```

Here is a working demo:  https://dotnetfiddle.net/vfXCqP

Comment: thank you so much for that help! :) I have one question for some clarification, Can we make the  SerializeForApiMethod method dynamic to apply to any model class instead of in the parameters saying "Model model". Because I have lots of Model class

Comment: I created a helper class and put the Attribute, Resolver and SerializeForApiMethod method in that class.

Comment: @ABIDKHAN Yes, of course, the `model` parameter in `SerializeForApiMethod` can just be of type `object`.  I've updated my answer and the fiddle.

Comment: in my model class  I am using the UseWithApiMethods doing the get and set. But then I created a instance of the class model to pass the values.  So i created two UseWithApiMethods and one instance of the model class. But then when I use the SerializeForApiMethod(model, "methodname") it takes all the values instead of just the method values

Comment: please can you have a look at the original question, I edited to get some idea on how should I assign the values, so it serializes only those using the method name specified

Comment: I originally made the resolver so that if you put no `[UseWithApiMethods]` attribute on a particular property, it would still be serialized.  It sounds like you want it to exclude the ones that have no `[UseWithApiMethods]` attribute, is that correct?

Comment: I am just trying to assign the values to the ones when I created the instance of the model class. And then using the method name to parse only those values that are associated with that method name in when using the SerializeForApiMethod. I want to exclude the ones that I did not mention the method name when using SerializeForApiMethod

Comment: I updated my answer.  The resolver should work how you want now.  (I changed `if (att != null && ...)` to `if (att == null || ...)` )

Comment: Thanks I used that but It only picks up the first value. If I have more than one then it does not pick that up.  Ex I have  id and parentId when using the method name that takes those values it only picks id and serializes it but leaves the parentid

Comment: You don't have an attribute on `parentId`.  Grouping the properties together in the code doesn't make the attribute on the first property apply to all of the properties.  You have to add an attribute to each property you want serialized, like shown in the example `Model` class in my answer.

Comment: Do you mean adding the attribute in the {get; set} because I did. I have both id and parentId  and then i set the values for both in the model class instance

Comment: Yes, but you only added the attribute before `public int Id { get; set; }`.  You need to also add it before `public int parentId { get; set; }`.  So you would have: `[UseWithApiMethods("UpdateEndpointsFromTags")] public int id { get; set; } [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateEndpointsFromTags")] public int parentId { get; set; }`

Comment: Thanks, I understand. Its is possible to separate the attrtibutes's values when assigning them. Because two of them are of <List> and others are just int. Since I have it like. For the id and parentid it takes it as a List                                                                         
         public static TagModel model = new TagModel
        {
            endpointIds = new List<int> { -2147483612, -2147483611 },
            tagIds = new List<int> { 35, 37 },
            
            id = -2147483639,
            parentId = 37

        };

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to do.  What do you mean by "separate the attributes' values"?

Comment: i am talking about the complex json payloads. when we have the multiple root objects. How can set the attributes for that ?. I have posted a picture on the original question of the payload. Also posted the payload in the question for your reference

Comment: I think you should open a new question explaining fully what you are trying to do.  In the new question you can add a link back to this one if it helps provide context.

Comment: I have opened a separate question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60782852/how-can-i-set-the-attributes-and-its-values-for-a-complex-json-payload-and-seria