# How can I set the attributes and its values for a complex Json payload and serialize?

Tags: c#, .net, json, api, serialization

I have the following structure in my framework.  I have a helper where I have the following Attribute code, Resolver code and the Serialization method.  Link to this in the other part of the question [How to create one model class to use with multiple API methods that require different JSON payloads?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60747225/how-to-create-one-model-class-to-use-with-multiple-api-methods-that-require-diff/60762886?noredirect=1#comment107540512_60762886)

I now have any API that takes a Payload that is large with root object.  How can I use the SerializeForApiMethod method for this, since it has the root object. I am trying to set the values in the same model object reference for this Jsonpayload.

//Here is the Json schema

```
{
  "tagNode": {
    "query": null,
    "type": 0,
    "filter": null,
    "ldapPaths": null,
    "editPermissions": 0,
    "id": 0,
    "disallowed": false,
    "name": "NewTag"
  },
  "parentId": 0
}

//Model class
public class TagModel
{
   public static TagModel mode = new TagModel
   {
            endpointIds = new List<int> { -2147483612, -2147483611 },
            tagIds = new List<int> { 35, 37 }, 
            id = -2147483639,
            parentId = 37,
            nodeId = 1,
            oldParentId = null,
            isEndpoint = false,
            state = 2,
            destinationTag = 2,



   };

    //This Object I am Confused on how to Serialize as above schema it in the 
   //same class whichI w ant to set the values inside the TagModel instance. 
    //Also has same attributes like id and parentId used already in the 
    //other methods and also this complex payload has a class TagNode which is 
    //the root object. 
     [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateTag")]
     public TagNode tagNode { get; set; }
     public object query { get; set; }
     public int type { get; set; }
     public object filter { get; set; }
     public object ldapPaths { get; set; }
     public int editPermissions { get; set; }
     public int id { get; set; }
     public bool disallowed { get; set; }
     public string name { get; set; }
     public int parentId { get; set; }



             //For this Object I am able to serialize it
           [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateTagToRoot")]
            public int nodeId { get; set; }
            [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateTagToRoot")]
            public object oldParentId { get; set; }
            [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateTagToRoot")]
            public bool isEndpoint { get; set; }
            [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateTagToRoot")]
            public int state { get; set; }
            [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateTagToRoot")]
            public int destinationTag { get; set; }



              //For this Object I am able to serialize it
            [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateEndpointsToTags")]
            public List<int> endpointIds { get; set; }
            [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateEndpointsToTags")]
            public List<int> tagIds { get; set; }


          //For this Object I am able to serialize it
           [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateEndpointsFromTags")]
           public int id { get; set; }
           [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateEndpointsFromTags")] 
           public int parentId { get; set; }


}

}
```

Comment: Why would you paste an image ? Not only are they are annoying, they are counter productive we cant copy and paste the data in them, search engines cant index the content

Comment: @MichaelRandall I have removed the image and put the payload with the object

Comment: What are the API methods that you intend to use this model with?  And which properties should be serialized with which API methods?  I don't see anything that would prevent you from using the `[UseWithApiMethods]` attributes on this complex model differently than you would with a simple model.  What specifically are you confused about?

Comment: @BrianRogers I am confused on how to achieve it in the using the same Model class I have "TagModel". Also since I have used some of the attributes in another payload. It does allow me to use those same ones again unless I rename them like id and parentId. Can I assign them in another way. I updated the question as to what i am trying to achieve.

Comment: What is the definition of the `TagNode` class?

Comment: We need a fully reproducible example. We also need the actual output and the desired output.  Otherwise it is very difficult to understand what you want

Answer (score 0):

To get the JSON payload you want using the custom resolver from the other question, you would need your class structure to look like this:

```
public class TagModel
{
    [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateTag")]
    public TagNode tagNode { get; set; }

    public class TagNode
    {
        [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateTag")]
        public object query { get; set; }

        [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateTag")]
        public int type { get; set; }

        [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateTag")]
        public object filter { get; set; }

        [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateTag")]
        public object ldapPaths { get; set; }

        [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateTag")]
        public int editPermissions { get; set; }

        [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateTag")]
        public int id { get; set; }

        [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateTag")]
        public bool disallowed { get; set; }

        [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateTag")]
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateEndpointsFromTags", "UpdateTag")]
    public int parentId { get; set; }

    ... (other properties for your other API methods) ...
}
```

Note that you must put `[UseWithApiMethods("UpdateTag")]` on the `tagNode` property in the root class *and also* on all the properties within the `TagNode` child class that you want to include in the JSON.  (This is necessary because the resolver will only include properties that you specifically mark with a `[UseWithApiMethods]` attribute. So you need to mark them all if you want to include them all).

For the `parentId` property, you were already using it for the `UpdateEndpointsFromTags` method, but that is no problem; you can also reuse it for other methods like `UpdateTag`.  You just need to add the method names to the `[UseWithApiMethods]` attribute like this:

```
    [UseWithApiMethods("UpdateEndpointsFromTags", "UpdateTag")]
    public int parentId { get; set; }
```

Here is a fiddle which demonstrates: https://dotnetfiddle.net/6TqbFz

Hopefully this is what you are looking for and resolves your confusion.

Comment: Ok makes sense. What if I want to use a different values for the parentId in "UpdateTag" and "UpdateEndpointsFromTags". Currently I have set to 37. But I want to set that to another number. Without effecting the method "UpdateEndpointsFromTags". The reason for this is I want to run them all in one click.

Comment: Then create a new instance of TagModel and set the property to whatever you need to.  See the fiddle in my answer.  It shows doing exactly that.

Comment: Yeah I checked the fiddle. And that exactly what i am trying to do but not able to create with the same reference name "model" under the class not allowed. It throws an error "The class already contains a definition for model" .  Am I missing something?

Comment: Are you trying to create multiple static instances of TagModel with the same property name `model` within the TagModel class?  If so, you can't do that.  Either give the static properties different names (for example, you could call one `defaultModel` and another one `modelForUpdate`), or create the model instances *outside* of the TagModel class instead of using static instances (this is a more typical solution), or make a one or more factory methods to create the model instances.  There are many possible solutions.

Comment: Okay I went with changing the static properties names. Since I want to hold all attributes and its value in the same class for now.  But today i am getting StackOverflowException. My test are not running. I posted in a different question. Can this be due to overload og the getter and setter? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60802619/how-to-fix-the-following-issue-with-test-not-being-executed-in-visual-studio